# function 'normrnd' in excutable compiled by matlab mcc doesn't work

Tags: matlab, compilation, mcc

I have a file named `myfunction.m`,
the content is:

```
function []=myfunction()
Z = normrnd(0,1)
```

Each time I issue the comman `myfunction` in matlab, I get a random result.

Then, I compile myfunction.m using this command:

```
mcc -m myfunction.m
```

and I obtain an excutable named `myfunction`.

And I try to excute it in matlab using this command:

```
!myfunction
```

However the results I get are no longer random...instead it is a fixed number, which is 0.5377..

This is so wired. 
Why?
My OS is linux.

Comment: Are you [randomly seeding](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/rng.html) the random number generator (using current time for example)? Try adding `rng('shuffle')` at the start of your code (for recent versions of Matlab)

Comment: Tanks very much Luis. That works!